# How to find repeated column while consuming a XML file into dataset

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to consuming XML file into text. I need to get all the nodes and values, don't want to deal with attribute names, because it will be different names. I used the method,

```
StringReader theReader = new StringReader(xmlData);
try
{
    DataSet theDataSet = new DataSet();
    theDataSet.ReadXml(theReader);
    return theDataSet;
}
```

and then read all DataTable in DataSet and get the table name and column values and converted into text file like,

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(".") + "\\xmlfiletables.txt", sb.ToString());
```

**But the issue comes like while convert xml into DataSet,**

Cannot add a column named `<some_column_name>`: a nested table with the same name already belongs to this DataTable.

So how can I resolve this (**identify repeated column and rename**)? and is there any other way to traverse in xml and write to text file?

Comment: Do you want write xml string in txt file, correct? I mean xml format in txt file.

Comment: Use [XDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) to do what you want. Dataset will not work because you have duplicate columns and/or table names which is/are not allowed. Thus you will get the error you are getting.

Comment: @CodingYoshi you said it. duplicate columns are not allowing. I will try the XDocument method.

Comment: @GaurangDave I had tried for the nodes and values. But my XML file is a big one and having more records under each node( tables). So I tried to get schema ( tabels and columns if consider DataSet) from xml and write into text file.